# MYSQL - ORDER AND CONCAT 2 or more FILEDS

Tags: mysql, field, concatenation

I Have this situation and I need the second table as a result. I have to Order the filels "TYPEn" and concat () them.

```
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | TYPE1| TYPE2 | TYPE3 | TYPE4 | TYPE5 |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | D    | C     |    A  |       |       |
|  2 | F    | D     |    C  |       |       |
|  3 | C    | L     |    A  |       |       |
|  4 | T    | O     |    M  |       |       |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+



+----+------+
| ID | RES  |
+----+------+
|  1 | ACD  |
|  2 | CDF  |
|  3 | ACL  |
|  4 | MOT  |
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

That you are trying to perform this operation at all is highly indicative of a denormalised schema.  You should consider [normalising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema, which would greatly simplify this operation.

As things stand, you can effectively (albeit very inefficiently) create normalised data structures on the fly and then use them:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(TYPE ORDER BY TYPE SEPARATOR '') RES FROM (
  SELECT ID, TYPE1 TYPE FROM myTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, TYPE2 FROM myTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, TYPE3 FROM myTable
) t GROUP BY ID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c97fe/1/0).

Comment: great! I know is not normalized, I will think to make a rel table like ID, type, typenumber . Thank you a lot!